# ios collaborative development - pair programming

Tags: ios, macos

Do you have developers located around the World - if so, do you do any collaborative development. Like Google Docs for Xcode/AppCode or any other tool.

Update: I am thinking realtime coding, together with another person somewhere in the World - like Google Docs, where you can invite and type together.

The question is; can this be done in any productive way?

Thanks for any input

Comment: You're talking about git/subversion.

Comment: No, more like Google Docs. See update.

Comment: This would be really useful for distributed Dojos!

Comment: I would love to do such kind of collaborative programming. I am also an iOS dev. Since this question is asked 3 years back, hope you have find some such kind of platform. Please let me know about that.

Comment: Hi @fpg1503 Since then moved to Flutter and then using VSCode collaborative features - this minimizes the need of XCode ide. Happy coding :-)

Comment: @ShubhamOjha sorry wrong user id